# I need to alter a sqlite3 table to add FTS3

Tags: sqlite, alter-table, fts3

I need the ability to add FTS3 to a sqlite3 table after it was created, not as it is created.  Does anyone know the ALTER syntax to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support altering a table from a normal table to an [FTS3](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) table. All you can do with [`ALTER TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) is change the table name or add columns.

You will have to use [`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html) to make the FTS3 table and then copy the data.

Comment: Thanks for the quality answer.  Unfortunately I am creating the database using sqlalchemy so that it works with different databases.  I have to add the FTS3 after the table is created.  I wonder if possibly sqlalchemy has a special declaration for sqlite3 and fts3 when modeling the tables.